# Select from three tables with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've three tables

```
students_first_semester_mark (StudentdID,Subject, Semester_I_Mark )
students_second_semester_mark (StudentdID,Subject, Semester_II_Mark )
students_third_semester_mark (StudentdID,Subject, Semester_III_Mark )
```

I want to have the following kind of output:

```
_________________________________________________________________________________
|StudentdID  | Subject |  Semester_I_Mark|  Semester_II_Mark |  Semester_III_Mark
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

Please note that `Semester_I_Mark` or `Semester_II_Mark` may have Null values.

I'm eager for your answers.

Comment: Any particular reason to use three tables?

Comment: Yes, fix your schema: student_id, subject_id, semester, mark

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```sql
SELECT [students_first_semester_mark].[StudentdID]
      ,[students_first_semester_mark].[Subject]
      ,[students_first_semester_mark].[Semester_I_Mark]
      ,[students_second_semester_mark].[Semester_II_Mark]
      ,[students_third_semester_mark].[Semester_III_Mark]
FROM [students_first_semester_mark]
JOIN [students_second_semester_mark] ON [students_second_semester_mark].[StudentdID] = [students_first_semester_mark].[StudentdID]
JOIN [students_third_semester_mark] ON [students_third_semester_mark].[StudentdID] = [students_second_semester_mark].[StudentdID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all students will not appear in all subjects.

It will be bit tricky to achieve it in MySQL as it doesn't support `full outer join`.

To derive `FULL OUTER JOIN`, you need a `LEFT JOIN` UNION `RIGHT JOIN`. As in your case, there are 3 tables, you would need to repeat this for first 2 tables and then UNION them. So the query will be pretty complex to look.

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69dab585c368ada459322acf224545a5)

```
select * from (
    select coalesce(fs.studentdid,t.studentdid) as STUDENTDID
    ,coalesce(fs.subject,t.subject) as subject 
    ,fs.semester_i_mark,fs.semester_ii_mark,t.semester_iii_mark
    from
    (
    select
    coalesce(f.studentdid,s.studentdid) as STUDENTDID,
    coalesce(f.subject,s.subject) as subject
    ,f.semester_i_mark,s.semester_ii_mark
    from
        STUDENTS_FIRST_SEMESTER_MARK f
        left join
        STUDENTS_SECOND_SEMESTER_MARK s
            on f.studentdid=s.studentdid
            and f.subject=s.subject
    UNION
    select
    coalesce(f.studentdid,s.studentdid) as STUDENTDID,
    coalesce(f.subject,s.subject) as subject
    ,f.semester_i_mark,s.semester_ii_mark
    from
        STUDENTS_FIRST_SEMESTER_MARK f
        right join
        STUDENTS_SECOND_SEMESTER_MARK s
            on f.studentdid=s.studentdid
            and f.subject=s.subject
    ) fs

    LEFT JOIN 
        STUDENTS_THIRD_SEMESTER_MARK t
            on fs.STUDENTDID=t.studentdid
            and fs.subject=t.subject
) u1
UNION
select * from (
    select coalesce(fs.studentdid,t.studentdid) as STUDENTDID
    ,coalesce(fs.subject,t.subject) as subject 
    ,fs.semester_i_mark,fs.semester_ii_mark,t.semester_iii_mark
    from
    (
    select
    coalesce(f.studentdid,s.studentdid) as STUDENTDID,
    coalesce(f.subject,s.subject) as subject
    ,f.semester_i_mark,s.semester_ii_mark
    from
        STUDENTS_FIRST_SEMESTER_MARK f
        left join
        STUDENTS_SECOND_SEMESTER_MARK s
            on f.studentdid=s.studentdid
            and f.subject=s.subject
    UNION
    select
    coalesce(f.studentdid,s.studentdid) as STUDENTDID,
    coalesce(f.subject,s.subject) as subject
    ,f.semester_i_mark,s.semester_ii_mark
    from
        STUDENTS_FIRST_SEMESTER_MARK f
        right join
        STUDENTS_SECOND_SEMESTER_MARK s
            on f.studentdid=s.studentdid
            and f.subject=s.subject
    ) fs

    RIGHT JOIN 
        STUDENTS_THIRD_SEMESTER_MARK t
            on fs.STUDENTDID=t.studentdid
            and fs.subject=t.subject
) u2
```

Coalesce is used so that any not null values of `studentdid` and `subject` are returned as we are using `outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest answer that I can think of.

```
SELECT T1.StudentdID,T1.Subject,T1.Semester_I_Mark,            
       T2.Semester_II_Mark, T3.Semester_III_Mark
FROM students_first_semester_mark T1, students_second_semester_mark T2, 
     students_third_semester_mark T3
JOIN T2 ON T1.StudentdID = T2.StudentdID
JOIN T3 ON T1.StudentdID = T3.StudentdID
```

Comment: That's what i'm talking about Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
 SELECT table1.StudentdID, table1.Subject, 
  table1.Semester_I_Mark, table2.Semester_II_Mark, 
  table3.Semester_III_Mark 
 FROM students_first_semester_mark  table1
 INNER JOIN students_second_semester_mark  table2 
  ON table1.StudentdID = table2.StudentdID
 INNER JOIN students_third_semester_mark   table3 
  ON table1.StudentdID = table3.StudentdID
```